# Opening a Datastore in iOS Dropbox Sync API 3.0

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

One of the new features of the 3.0 Datastore API is the ability to use local datastores that will later sync up with Dropbox when the user decides to link your app to Dropbox. I'm wondering how the process of opening datastores differs now.

For example, this is how I currently open a datastore:

```
DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
self.store = [DBDatastore openDefaultStoreForAccount:account error:nil];
```

How do I get a `DBAccount` without a linked account? Maybe I don't. :)

On that same note, what is the process for opening a datastore with `openDefaultStoreForAccount` if there is no `account` present?

I just noticed `openDefaultLocalStoreForAccountManager`:

Is this how it's used? And does this still work later when there *is* a linked account?

```
self.store = [DBDatastore openDefaultLocalStoreForAccountManager:[DBAccountManager sharedManager] error:nil];
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/99/using-the-new-local-datastores-feature? Does that answer your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/99/using-the-new-local-datastores-feature:

```
// If the user has linked a Dropbox account for the first time...
if (_justLinked) {
    if (_localDatastoreManager && self.account) {
        // Perform a one-time migration to move from the local datastore to a remote one.
        [_localDatastoreManager migrateToAccount:self.account error:nil];
        _localDatastoreManager = nil;
    }
}
if (!_store) {
    // If there's a linked account, use that.
    if ([[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount]) {
        _store = [DBDatastore openDefaultStoreForAccount:self.account error:nil];
    // Otherwise, use a local datastore.
    } else {
        _store = [DBDatastore openDefaultLocalStoreForAccountManager:[DBAccountManager sharedManager]
                                                               error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Another question for you. In the case where a user unlinks the app from Dropbox, do I need to reinstate the local datastore? It'd be cool if the API could manage the back and forth between linked and unlinked states automatically.

Comment: I believe the migration is one-time and one-way. If a user unlinks your app, the local cache of the datastore will be deleted anyway.